# Concise way to get the single element contained in a HashSet, C#

Tags: c#, hashset

I know for sure that at a particular point in my program a `HashSet` I've constructed will only contain a single element. I know I can get the element by doing this:

```
foreach (int num in myHashSet)
{
    return num;
}
```

But I don't like the idea of using a for loop when I'm certain that the `HashSet` only contains a single item. I know `HashSet`s are unordered and understand why using, say, an array-style index won't work. Are there any solutions that will make it clear that only a single element exists in the `HashSet`? I feel that with a loop this property isn't clear.

Comment: `int num = myHashSet.Single();`

Comment: Where is that function defined? I get a compilation error when I try it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iwe3Eb

Comment: @Adam add a `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HashSet<int> ihs = new HashSet<int>();
ihs.Add(12);
if (ihs.Count() == 1)
{
    int x = ihs.First();
}
```

Comment: `using System.Linq;`